# java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver (Didn't find class)

Tags: android, crash, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, android-broadcastreceiver

We are using a 3rd party library for ad mediation that declares different activities, receivers and services in its manifest. Not all of these are going to actually be implemented in the app.

I have started seeing exceptions such as this one from users of our app:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver
>   com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "com.inmobi.commons.core.utilities.uid.ImIdShareBroadCastReceiver" on
>   path: DexPathList

My question is - will Android attempt to instantiate receivers (or other components defined in the AndroidManifest) if they are not present?

I have not found any documentation that describes this particular scenario.

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: @Oli can you share your solution.. I am also face this issue

Comment: @I also have this crash i use appodeal ad lib

Answer (score 0):

1) To solve the problem you need to make sure that inmobi.jar and picasso.jar (it's needed for inmobi) are located in the libs folder. By default picasso is located in the optional folder. You have to move it from optional to libs.

Also, for picasso you need to add this: compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2' into build.gradle file.

Also, if you use the proguard file, you need to add the following for inmobi:

```
-keep class com.inmobi.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.inmobi.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-keep class com.squareup.picasso.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.squareup.picasso.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**
-keep class com.moat.** {*;}
-dontwarn com.moat.**
```

2) If you are not using the build type specified above, you need to enable multidex. Then you have to use nodex build. Latest nodex version for Android native is [here](https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/appodeal-android/2.1.10/Appodeal-Android-SDK-2.1.10-280218-all-nodex.zip)

You can find the documentation [here](https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=1&full=1&platform=1#p_1)